# Complex Analyisis: Exponential Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose I have this domain:

$$D = \{z \in\Bbb C: \text{Re}(z) \leq \text{Im}(z) < \text{Re}(z) + 2\pi\}.$$

I have to show that the exponential function restricted to $D$ is one-to-one.

To prove that is injective, I think I just need to say that the function restricted to $D$ is injective. But I don't know how to prove that it is surjective.

Comment: In your notation, does one-to-one mean injective or bijective? In the latter case, this is not true: 0 is not in the image of the complex exponential function.

Comment: one-to-one mean injective and surjective

Comment: As said in my earlier comment, you will only be able to show that $e^\cdot: D \to \mathbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is bijective, since $0$ is not in the image.

Comment: I know, but how can I prove that?

Comment: Note that $e^{a+ib} = e^a (\cos b + i\sin b)$,hence $|e^{a+ib}| = e^a$. Do you know that $e^\cdot: \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$?

Comment: Ok, yes I know how is e

Answer (score 1):

"One-to-one" should never be used in mathematical writing, and here is why:

[image: wiki]

Write exponential map in polar coordinates $e^{x+iy}=e^x e^{iy}$. As $x$ runs from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, the term $e^x$ attains all positive values, and is injective. For each fixed $x$, as $y$ varies in $[x,x+2\pi)$, the valus of $e^{iy}$ cover the unit circle (bijectively). Hence, we have a bijection onto $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$. (As Johannes Kloos already said in comments.)

Comment: No, "one-to-one" gives a descriptive hint at its definition.  It's the phrase "one-to-one correspondence" that shouldn't be used.  Especially since I had to look up the definition of "correspondence", and I don't see immediately why a one-to-one correspondence would have to be a bijection.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: as a non-native speaker perhaps you should not say something

Comment: @Herbert, That's rude.  I am a native speaker.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: I no, I no!